# How to fadeOut/In background-image using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fadeOut/In the `background-image` property of `body` using the following code:

```
var main = function() {

var currentPath = 0;
var MudaCenario = function(){
    var paths = ["url('res/teatro1.jpg')", "url('res/teatro2.jpg')", "url('res/teatro3.jpg')" ];


    currentPath++;
    if( currentPath > paths.length ) currentPath = 0;

    $('body').fadeIn(400).css('background-image', paths[currentPath]);
    };

setInterval(MudaCenario, 2000);


};

$(document).ready(main);
```

On my `css` I got:

```
body {
left: 0;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
background-image: url('../res/teatro1.jpg');
-webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
}
```

The images are indeed being changed but with no fade effect. I also tried:

```
$('body').animate({ background-image : paths[currentPath] }, 400);
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm trying this but when I add the div it just messes up with all my layout structure

Answer (score 0):

You're targetting the `body` with the `fadeIn`. Effectively, that means you're fading the `body` element into the page, but it's already there.

My best suggestion is to use a CSS transition on the `background-image` property of `body`:

```
body {
    -webkit-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: I added this to `body` and remove fadeIn function from the JS code and still not working. But thanks anyway

Comment: Can you try other values for the transition, other than `ease-in-out`? What happens? Look at the console, see what changes between transitions.

Comment: Yeah, but what does that mean? It's like phoning in customer support saying your computer doesn't work, and after 30 minutes on the phone, it turns out that you set it on fire and that's why it doesn't work anymore. Be specific.

Comment: It means that didn't worked. The images just changes "abruptly" with no fade effect. When I changed things you recommended the behaviour stood the same. I posted the css part and the JS already. My `<body>` opening has no attributes setted up (just the `<body></body>`) Do you know anything else I can say to help you? I uploaded the HTML code but I don't know if this will help: http://pastebin.com/dA98RR2N